# mktemp -d not creating temp directory

Tags: linux, mktemp

I am trying to create a temporary directory using `mktemp -d` but it is not creating a directory. When I try to run `cd $(mktemp -d)` it takes me to my home folder. This behavior is similar to `cd` .

When I try to run `mktemp -d` and check the exit code using `echo $?` it return `248` as the exit code.

What is going on?

Comment: 248 is an unusual return code for `mktemp`. Assuming you're on linux, try `strace`ing it, and see which syscall fails.

Comment: `mktemp` should also return an error message.

Comment: That is the strange thing! It does not return any error message and the return code is cryptic. It silently fails!

Comment: What version of `mktemp` are you running?

Comment: What is the output of `type mktemp` command ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `$(TMPDIR)` is set to a non-existent directory or one to which your user lacks write+execute permissions.